# Why does DataFrameWriter.parquet() write files/partitions with no data in them

Tags: apache-spark

**Context**

I am trying to migrate from Spark 1.6.1 to Spark 2.0.0. My issues here are probably not entirely related to the Spark version and more to do with the compression formats too. I am trying to read a parquet file compressed in gzip format written by Spark 1.6.1. I needed to add an extra literal column and save it back to disk. This process is now happening using Spark 2.0.0. I noticed that the output contained a large number of small files with just the metadata. Previously when I loaded these parquet files I used to get as many partitions (df.rdd.partitions.size) as the number of splits in the parquet on disk. Later I realized this is due to the gzip format being not splittable. But, I don't understand why Spark is writing empty partitions back to disk. Spark 2.0 defaults to snappy for compressing the parquet files.

**What I know so far**

- `gzip` (the default in 1.6.1) being a non-splittable format, would result in as many in-memory partitions as the splits on disk.
- Using `snappy` allows Spark to use the available executors to load the data and that explains the dynamic nature of the number of partitions.
- `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "true")`
- I have also turned off schema merging.

**Questions**

- Why is Spark writing empty files to disk?
- How do I make Spark optimize the size of the partition to be 128MB per file? (I know this can be achieved through repartition/coalesce. I need to calculate the parameter for repartitioning though)

**Commands which verify my claims**

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hive/conf /home/srikar/spark-2.0.0/bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-class-path '/etc/hive/conf' --num-executors 100 --executor-memory 6g --driver-memory 8g

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val df = spark.read.parquet("/user/srikary/data/2016/07/05")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [user_uuid: string, client_uuid: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.rdd.partitions.size
res1: Int = 95

scala> df.write.parquet("/user/srikary/test/partitions_test")
```

Output from listing the two directories used in the test above

```
srikar@localhost:~$ hadoop fs -ls  /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05
Found 21 items
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar          0 2016-10-24 01:09 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar        473 2016-10-24 01:09 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/_common_metadata
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar      12303 2016-10-24 01:09 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/_metadata
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34576052 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00000-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34574386 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00001-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34575034 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00002-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34588117 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00003-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34578050 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00004-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34584603 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00005-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34595888 2016-10-24 01:09 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00006-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34582493 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00007-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34594552 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00008-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34584819 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00009-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34601397 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00010-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34580279 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00011-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34651221 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00012-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34605249 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00013-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34561204 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00014-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34603328 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00015-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34575536 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00016-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikar srikar   34597036 2016-10-24 01:08 /user/srikary/data/2016/07/05/part-r-00017-982889cd-a118-46a0-8349-732f8c3fd678.gz.parquet
```

With `snappy`:

```
srikary@localhost:~$ hadoop fs -ls /user/srikary/test/partitions_test
Found 96 items
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary          0 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00000-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00001-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59317007 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00002-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00003-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00004-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00005-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59321056 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00006-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00007-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00008-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00009-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59322819 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00010-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00011-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00012-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00013-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59313102 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00014-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00015-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00016-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00017-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59323721 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00018-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00019-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00020-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00021-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59316186 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00022-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00023-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00024-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00025-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59323141 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00026-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00027-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00028-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00029-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59322078 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00030-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00031-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00032-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00033-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59325795 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00034-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00035-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00036-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00037-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59329053 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00038-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00039-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00040-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00041-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59317677 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00042-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00043-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00044-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00045-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59324442 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00046-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00047-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00048-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00049-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59325743 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00050-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00051-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00052-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00053-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59317381 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00054-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00055-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00056-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00057-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59324735 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00058-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00059-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00060-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00061-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59320296 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00062-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00063-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00064-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00065-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59312148 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00066-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00067-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00068-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00069-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59326905 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00070-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00071-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00072-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00073-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary   59326284 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00074-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00075-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00076-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00077-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00078-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00079-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00080-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00081-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00082-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00083-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00084-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00085-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00086-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00087-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00088-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        467 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00089-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00090-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00091-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00092-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00093-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 srikary srikary        516 2016-12-12 00:45 /user/srikary/test/partitions_test/part-r-00094-99ba2a41-5c27-4e30-9ebc-4b055013ec66.snappy.parquet
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Spark writing empty files to disk?

It writes partition content. It doesn't matter if it is empty or not. It is normal behavior on Spark and related systems.

> How do I make Spark optimize the size of the partition to be 128MB per file? (I know this can be achieved through repartition/coalesce. I need to calculate the parameter for repartitioning though)

This is a hard question. Getting exact value for multiple partitions won't be possible in general. Parquet is applies different compression techniques on data and its content is as important as the raw amount.